# A question on infinite arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics, computational-number-theory, arithmetic-progression

I was working on a problem that consisted of deciding if the language a finite automaton (the alphabet of which is $\{0,1\}$ and the words accepted are binary encoded positive integers) contains an infinite arithmetic progression, and I bumped into the following problem:

Say we have a finite bases set $B$ of natural numbers and a finite set of tuples $T=\{(m_1, a_1), \dots, (m_t, a_t)\}$ with $m_i \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots, t\}$, can we decide if the following set $S$ contains an infinite arithmetic progression:
$$S_0 = B$$
$$S_{i+1} = S_i \cup \big\{ s \mid s = n * m_j + a_j \text{ for some } n \in S_i,  1 \leq j \leq t\big\}$$
$$S = \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} S_j$$

Edit2: This is a decision problem and goes like this: For given finite $B$ and $T$, can we decide whether $S$ contains an infinite arithmetic progression? And if we can, how?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Edit1: I don’t know if it makes the problem more interesting or easier but I actually have an additional constraint: For each $i$, $m_i$ is a power of $2$ and $a_i < m_i$.

Comment: Isn't the set $S$ you have written down finite, and thus never contains an infinite arithmetic progression? Probably I have misunderstood or you meant to write something else...

Comment: Also, unless $k=t=1$, the conditions $1\ge i\ge k$ and $1\ge j\ge t$, which imply $k\le1$ and $t\le1$, respectively, don't make sense. This question needs some careful rewriting.

Comment: Yes, I am very sorry. I have edited it.

Comment: Now in the definition of your set $S$ appears the set $S$ itself.

Comment: Yes, I do mean so. I am trying to make a inductive definition. Sorry again, if this is not formal enough, I am writing it more precisely.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand. You mean you can use as $n$ any number you already generated, right? If so, write it down inductively, as you said.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte, yes, that’s what I meant. Did it.

Comment: In general the answer is no: if e.g. $t=1$, $b=1$, $m_1=2$, $a_1=0$, then $S=\{2^n: n\in\mathbb N\}$.  More generally, if the numbers $m_i$ are too large w.r.to $t$, then $S$ has zero natural density and contains no infinite sequence $x_j=O(j)$.

Comment: If I  understand the question “can we know if…” means : “how can we decide if..”. That is, characterise the situation where S does contain an infinite arithmetic progression. It  seems an interesting question.

Comment: @PietroMajer, exactly!

Comment: I think that the condition you describe on $S$ is "$2$-recognizable"?

Comment: A necessary condition is that the set $S$ have positive density, which I think is equivalent to the claim that every string of bits is a subsequence of a string of bits obtained by concatenating the $a_i$. This is not sufficient. For example, we can take $B$ to consisting of only $3$, $t=2$, $(m_1,a_1)=(2,0)$, $(m_2,a_2)=2,1$. Then $S$ is all numbers whose second bit in their binary expansion is $1$, which does not contain an infinite arithmetic progression.